# Spring Boot auto configuration - Override an auto configured bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm attempting to override a bean definition from a library auto configuration and it isn't working. I'm overriding the definition to return a bean of the interface type - my own implementation, whereas the library auto configuration bean returns a concrete implementation.

Spring is finding my bean at startup, then overriding it with the library bean. I've tried using `@AutoConfigureAfter(LibraryConfig.class)` and making my bean `@Lazy` but nothing seems to work.

I've spent many a year staying clear of 'magical' code and this type of thing is a good case in point.

Comment: ..the bean *must* have the same (bean) `name`..and everything else depends on the overwritten bean..

Comment: You question is not clear, please add  your configuration class to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is indeed not clear, probably an example could help here.
Anyway, when an infrastructure-level bean is defined, the easiest way in spring boot to override it is just to provide your own configuration that will return the same interface (the bean with the given name)

for example, let's say, in some spring boot source/thirdparty there is the following code:

```
interface SomeInterface  {...}
public class ThirdpartyInternalImplementation implementsSomeInterface {...}

@Configuration 
public class ThirdPartyConfiguration {
   @Bean
   public SomeInterface someInterface () {
      return new ThirdpartyInternalImplementation();
   }
}
```

So now, let's assume, that in your source code you've provided another implementation of `SomeInterface` and you want to return it instead. So you should do something like this:

```
class MyCustomImplementation implements SomeInterface {}
..........................
@Configuration
public class MyOwnConfiguration {

    @Bean 
    public SomeInterface someInterface() {
        return MyCustomImplementation();
    }
}
```

This should be enough to register your custom implementation of `SomeInterface`.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing with the difference that ThirdPartyConfiguration is returning a concrete implementation of an interface. My override is returning the interface type. Spring is finding the bean in MyOwnConfiguration first, then overriding it with the bean in ThirdPartyConfiguration. The precise opposite of what I want.